# missing right parenthesis in oracle apex code

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am running this code in oracle apex interactive report page to show the students pictures, but it is keep throwing this error "ORA-06550: line 2, column 14: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis", however I checked there is not any parenthesis missing.

```
SELECT "ID", "NAME", decode(NVL(dbms_lob.getlength("PHOTO"),0),0,NULL,
      '<img 'src ="'|| apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P7_PHOTO',ID) ||'" width ="100"/>') from "#OWNER#."STUDENTS_INFO"
```

Comment: There's a stray `'` (before `img`). Remove that.

Comment: thanks @stickybit i just removed that now it is showing this error "ORA-06550: line 2, column 7: ORA-00936: missing expression" , the code looking lieke this  SELECT "ID", "NAME", decode(NVL(dbms_lob.getlength("PHOTO"),0),0,NULL,
      <img src ="' || apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P7_PHOTO',ID) || '" width ="100"/>')  image from "#OWNER#."STUDENTS_INFO"

Comment: Now you're missing a `'` before `<img` and a `"` after `#OWNER#`...

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong single quote just before src

```
SELECT "ID"
    , "NAME"
    , decode(NVL(dbms_lob.getlength("PHOTO"),0),0,NULL,
       '<img src ="'|| apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P7_PHOTO',ID) ||'" width ="100"/>') 
FROM "#OWNER#"."STUDENTS_INFO"
```

and missed  a double quote for "#OWNER#"

Comment: BTW, no need to include "#OWNER#". It's also not necessary to wrap all column or table names in double quotes. This is only necessary if they are case sensitive or contain special characters.

Comment: thanks @PatrickWolf  and Scais Edge, here i upload some photos in google drive it is not showing the picture now, in youtube when they run such a code it works i don't understand why it is not working in my end. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VqkkfoqNzowDP2gv4_OVII4QEqsN5Pd0?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  "ID",
        "NAME",
        DECODE(NVL(dbms_lob.getlength("PHOTO"),0),
        0,
        NULL,
        '<img src ="'|| apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P7_PHOTO',ID) ||'" width ="100"/>') PHOTO
FROM    "#OWNER#"."STUDENTS_INFO"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answers, when I run your code in the interactive report page of oracle apex 5.0 , and change the photo column to standard view it is not showing the picture, here i uploaded some of the screenshots for you. thanks alot from your efforts. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VqkkfoqNzowDP2gv4_OVII4QEqsN5Pd0?usp=sharing